# C++ Assumptions

Tags: c++, c++11

Once I saw a way in C++ to assume something, for example:

```
int x=7;

assume (x==7);//if not right a red error will appear and program will end.
```

Can someone please tell me what was the exact code for that? I have done a lot of research but found nothing since I forgot the original phrase.
(I want to use this for debugging)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are assertions? and why would you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253212/what-are-assertions-and-why-would-you-use-them)

Comment: Herb Sutter has a nice write up comparing **assertions** and **assumptions**:  [Assumptions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2064r0.pdf) (P2064 R0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for `assert`, cf. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert.

There is also `static_assert`, which does checking during compile time.

There was a proposal to add more pronounced system of "assumptions" to C++, called contracts (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1866.html), but its introduction to the language is postponed. If you are learning, you don't really need to read the document under that last URL.

Comment: it's better to use `static_assert` in this case

Comment: thank you, can you please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092094/avl-tree-scan-nodes-by-order I don't understand the answer

Comment: @phuclv: `x` is not a constant expression, so cannot be used for `static_assert`